# No /dev/tty in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, tty

I installed [ammonite](https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL) and got

```
(Scala 2.11.7 Java 1.8.0_45)
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
        at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
        at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
        at ammonite.terminal.TTY$.stty(Utils.scala:85)
        at ammonite.terminal.TTY$.init(Utils.scala:64)
        at ammonite.terminal.TermCore$.x$6$lzycompute$1(TermCore.scala:244)
        at ammonite.terminal.TermCore$.x$6$1(TermCore.scala:244)
        at ammonite.terminal.TermCore$.initialConfig$lzycompute$1(TermCore.scala:244)
        at ammonite.terminal.TermCore$.initialConfig$1(TermCore.scala:244)
        at ammonite.terminal.TermCore$.readLine(TermCore.scala:254)
        at ammonite.repl.frontend.AmmoniteFrontEnd.readLine(AmmoniteFrontEnd.scala:110)
        at ammonite.repl.frontend.AmmoniteFrontEnd.action(AmmoniteFrontEnd.scala:25)
        at ammonite.repl.Repl.action(Repl.scala:46)
        at ammonite.repl.Repl.loop$1(Repl.scala:79)
        at ammonite.repl.Repl.run(Repl.scala:97)
        at ammonite.repl.Main$.run(Main.scala:135)
        at ammonite.repl.Main$$anonfun$main$2.apply(Main.scala:82)
        at ammonite.repl.Main$$anonfun$main$2.apply(Main.scala:81)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at ammonite.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:81)
        at ammonite.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

despite `/dev/tty` and `/dev/ttyS0` exist in my cygwin. How can I fix it?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks, I have checked and cannot reproduce `stty`. The `/dev/tty` is missing solid-rock however.

Comment: @DavidPostill Running systty gives me`38400 baud; line = 0; ixany`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address

> despite `/dev/tty` and `/dev/ttyS0` existing in Cygwin. How can I fix it?

It's a known bug. See [Ammonite-REPL doesn't work on Windows #119](https://github.com/lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/119#issuecomment-138450198).